# why unsafe block with pointers is slower than regular version

Tags: c#

I am testing using unsafe and pointers on character match counting a 200 byte array along every position in a 1 meg long char array as an experiment with safe/unsafe/dll call speed comparison.

They are run in release mode with optimize code on, allow unsafe, no bounds checking.
Long char array is used purposely used to minimize calling overhead impacts.

The times i get are

> regular 560 ms
>
> unsafe  830 ms
>
> dll     205 ms

why is the unsafe slower??

```
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[1000000];
    byte[] check = new Byte[1000];
    [DllImport("sortitdev.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  //[DllImport("sortitfast.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]      
  //[DllImport("sortitpellas.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]        
    
    public unsafe static extern void sortitt([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] buffer);
    
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // do char array matching
    {
        byte match;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
            buffer[i]=(byte)rnd.Next(0,256);
        for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
            check[i]=(byte)rnd.Next(0,256);
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int kk=0;
        int jq=0;
        while(kk<999000)
        {
            kk++;
            match=0;
            for(jq=0;jq<199;jq++)
                if(buffer[kk+jq]==check[jq])match++;
            buffer[kk]=match;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        textBox1.Text= sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* bufptr=&buffer[0] , chckptr=&check[0])
            {
                byte* bufptrC=bufptr;  // modifiable pointer
                byte* chckptrC=chckptr;
                byte* bufhldptr;
                byte* chckhldptr;
                int k=999000;
                int jw=0;
                while(k>0)
                {
                    bufhldptr=bufptrC;
                    match=0;
                    chckhldptr=chckptrC;
                    for(jw=0;jw<199;jw++)
                        if(*bufhldptr++==*chckhldptr++)match++;
                    *bufptrC++=match;
                    k--;
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            textBox2.Text= sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        }
        sw.Reset();
        for(int tt=0;tt<200;tt++) buffer[tt]=(byte)tt;
        
        sw.Start();
        unsafe
        {
            fixed(byte* dadata=&buffer[0])
            {
                sortitt(buffer);
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        textBox3.Text= sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        int kll=(int)buffer[1];
        textBox4.Text= kll.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW I think you should use spaces more, it will make your code more readable. This is not code golf.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you run this without the debugger attached?

Comment: svick, yes ran without debugger.

Comment: You should format your code better. Use spaces, use newlines, use descriptive variable names. It seems that you are doing unncessary things in the unsafe version. Why use fixed(byte* ptr = &buff[0]) and not fixed(byte* ptr = buff) and why assign ptrs to others at the start.

Comment: I checked your code and your calculations 1 and 2 give different answers for the same input vector - algorithms are not really the same.

Comment: I also checked your code and I got 902 ms and 738 ms with unsafe being faster...

Comment: For bench-marking, remember this: **Build and run** without a debugger.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens and possibly with Visual Studio turned off. Sometimes, it did some slowing of code.

Comment: should add that i am using sharpdevelop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code, I did not get that your unsafe code was slower. However, I re-wrote your unsafe code (rather quickly - double check) but I believe this should be much simpler for you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
    byte[] check = new byte[200];

    private unsafe void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // do char array matching
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
        rnd.NextBytes(check);
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        byte match = 0;
        int kk = 0;
        int jq = 0;

        while (kk < 999000)
        {
            kk++;
            match = 0;
            for (jq = 0; jq < 199; jq++)
                if (buffer[kk + jq] == check[jq])
                    match++;
            buffer[kk] = match;
        }

        sw.Stop();
        textBox1.Text = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        fixed (byte* pCheck = check, pBuffer = buffer)
        {
            match = 0;
            kk = 0;
            jq = 0;

            while (kk < 999000)
            {
                kk++;
                match = 0;
                for (jq = 0; jq < 199; jq++)
                    if (pBuffer[kk + jq] == pCheck[jq])
                        match++;
                pBuffer[kk] = match;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        textBox2.Text = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
    }
}
```

results:

managed: 404 ms
unsafe: 284 ms

This was executed in release by right clicking project and starting new instance without debugger. I also checked my code and it gives the same result with both methods.

Comment: seems like pointer dereferencing is an extra step in dot net?

Comment: @KelseyBowman You can change it to pointer arithmetic if you wish, but I believe they are the same thing. i.e. ptr[5] is same as *(ptr + 5). I'll give it a try

Comment: if(*bufhldptr++==*chckhldptr++)match++;  In the old days of native code generation this type of stuff was faster because variables were already in processor registers. But this does not seem to apply to managed code ??

Comment: @KelseyBowman It seems to me that your version has a lot more variables (extra pointers defined). If there were an optimization to be made, I believe my version is proper enough for the optimizer to take care of it. Also, if you want the code to run faster, unroll the loop and read in 32/64 bits at a time depending on your architecture instead of byte-by-byte. That's probably going to be a real improvement.

Comment: found a serious issue with this speed test code, the buffer is overwritten in each test which leads to different conditions for subsequent tests, specifically how many times match++ is executed. I changed it so that each method runs the same input data and the results are much more consistent with unsafe being about 10% faster but still 2.3x as long as a c dll call.

Comment: @KelseyBowman I had noticed that too and tried two separate buffers, but I didn't show it

Comment: @KelseyBowman If speed is really important, I would optimize your C# code to read 32/64 bits at a time and parse out each byte and see if that helps. It is hard to know why the C is 2.3x faster. Is it your C code? (haven't seen it) Is it the C compiler optimization doing more? Is it just because it is C? My first thought is that 2.3x faster seems "awfully fast" I'm not sure it would normally be that much better.

Comment: Alan This was really just an academic exercise to see what the limits are. The C dll code is Mingw with compiler settings for P4 and optimize for fast, and appears nearly identical to the code in the unsafe loop. I suspect IL runtime doesn't access processor registers as well as native can for such a small tight loop. Thanks for your help.